# Find server response time in java

Tags: java, http, httpclient

I am using a third party service and calling them using httpClient. 
Though I  can measure total time for a request with code

```
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();        
    result = httpClient.execute(request);
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

My problem is that the total time of the request is very high. However third party deny  this stats. Hence i  want a breakdown of time taken in network lag v/s time spent on third party servers.

Is there  a way to do this in java

Comment: I don't think there is something in-buit into API, you might need to use something like network monitoring tools to calculate network lag.

Comment: Maybe the "debug/trace" logs from httpclient could help, see https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html

Comment: Have you tried to use FireBug?

Comment: What is their foundation for denying your stats?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about network management and belongs on [sf].

Comment: @Florian Stendel  - They reply with response to their stats. However those stats are biased as  they dont consider concurrency and load.

Comment: @VickyDesai
As Jim Garrison already pointed out it will be hard for you to measure something meaningful beyond your servers leaving network interface.

You may consider using a website-monitoring tool like Pingdom to do sample requests from across the world/country to gather additional response-time stats other than the ones taken from your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some effort I was able to find the split of response time, I have done that using curl & ProcessBuilder in java. Incase anyone faces the same problem PFB code to do the same

```
String OUTPUT_FORMAT = "\ntime_namelookup:    %{time_namelookup}\ntime_connect:  %{time_connect}\ntime_appconnect:  %{time_appconnect}\ntime_pretransfer:  %{time_pretransfer}\ntime_redirect:  %{time_redirect}\ntime_starttransfer:  %{time_starttransfer}\n----------\ntime_total:  %{time_total}\n";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(CURL,"-w" ,OUTPUT_FORMAT, "www.yoursite.com");
Process p = pb.start();
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
Integer i = null;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
while ((i = bis.read()) != -1) {        
    stringBuilder.append((char) i.byteValue());
}
System.out.println(stringBuilder);
```

Your Output shoulld be in following format

```
time_namelookup:  0.286
time_connect:  0.297
time_appconnect:  0.000
time_pretransfer:  0.298
time_redirect:  0.000
time_starttransfer:  0.317
----------
time_total:  0.317
```

Answer (score 2):

From the point of view of your Java code there is no visibility into the breakdown of time spent on the server vs network *latency* or transmission time.

To do a proper calculation you would need to

1. Profile the connection to determine average round-trip time and available network bandwidth.
2. Then using Wireshark examine the network traffic and calculate an approximate breakdown into latency (end-to-end delay, loosely the same as ping time), transmission delay (data size divided by bandwidth) and server response delay.

This still won't tell you if the delay is due to server slowness or something between you and the server that is proxying and delaying traffic.  For example, the end server could be very fast but the response could be delayed by a firewall (yours or theirs) that does deep packet inspection and is underpowered for the task.  It would barely affect `ping`/`traceroute` but seriously delay large data streams.  Truly debugging this will require cooperation with the owners of all the equipment between you and the server, and can be a frustrating experience.